# Paste: paste output from subshell to incoming content from pipeline

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, paste

Suppose I execute the following commands which **do** work:

```
seq 1 100 >  x
cat y_data | paste x /dev/stdin
```

Now, I would like to execute the following:

```
cat y_data | paste $(seq 1 100) /dev/stdin
```

However, I am in guess and check mode with various redirection permutations.  Is there a way to do this subshell redirection for paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` accepts filenames. You need something that can be treated as a filename, and when read, will produce the output of `seq 1 100`.

Creating a real file is one way. Another is *process substitution*:

```
cat y_data | paste <(seq 1 100) /dev/stdin | less
```

You can do this with multiple commands as well:

```
paste <(seq 1 100) <(tail -n 100 y_data) | less
```

Each `<(...)` will be replaced by a filename to a pipe that Bash sets up, and opening this filename for reading will read the command's output:

```
$ echo <(seq 1 3)
/dev/fd/63

$ cat <(seq 1 3)
1
2
3
```

You can similarly use `>(...)` to create a filename that can be written to, to pipe data to the command's stdin.

Comment: that is pretty awesome.